# Counting rows having greater than 1 - year grouping

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I currently have my query that counts patients that have a problem with an `id` of `16`:

```
SELECT
    YEAR(pbd.date_created), 
    COUNT(*)
FROM
    patient_booking_data pbd inner join problems p on pbd.pid = p.pid
WHERE 
    p.problem_list_id IN (16)       
GROUP BY
    YEAR(pbd.date_created)
```

This groups the number of patients based on the year they entered the our system `date_created`.

[image]

**I am trying to figure out how many returned within the same year.**

I've tried something like this:

```
SELECT
    YEAR(pbd.date_created), 
    COUNT(*)
FROM
    patient_booking_data pbd inner join problems p on pbd.pid = p.pid
WHERE 
    p.problem_list_id IN (16)
    AND pbd.pid IN (
        SELECT pid FROM patient_booking_data GROUP BY pid HAVING count(*) > 1
    )
GROUP BY
    YEAR(pbd.date_created)
```

But that will count the `pid` (patient_id) if they have re-entered the system even if it is a different year.

`patient_booking_data` looks something like:

```
id   | pid   | booking_no    | date_created     | release_date
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1    | 565   | 12-3431       | 2012-08-10       | 2012-08-12
2    | 1231  | 12-1125       | 2012-08-11       | 2012-08-28
3    | 831   | 12-7897       | 2012-08-11       | 2012-08-11
4    | 2365  | 12-1254       | 2012-09-02       | 2012-09-03
5    | 565   | 12-5698       | 2012-10-10       | 2012-10-25
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Wouldn't a simple `HAVING count(*) > 1` on the main query do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query below will return all patients that have visited twice or more during the same year:

```
SELECT
    pbd.id,
    YEAR(pbd.date_created), 
    COUNT(*)
FROM
    patient_booking_data pbd inner join problems p on pbd.pid = p.pid
WHERE 
    p.problem_list_id IN (16)       
GROUP BY
    YEAR(pbd.date_created), pbd.id
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

You can count the number of such patients per year by doing another group by on a derived table

```
SELECT COUNT(*), y FROM (
    SELECT
        pbd.id,
        YEAR(pbd.date_created) y
    FROM
        patient_booking_data pbd inner join problems p on pbd.pid = p.pid
    WHERE 
        p.problem_list_id IN (16)       
    GROUP BY
        YEAR(pbd.date_created), pbd.id
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) t1 GROUP BY y
```